# Is there a way to globally access/update a user controlled data set in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a React Native app and need to access a data set in multiple locations that the user sets/changes in the app settings. Currently I have it as regular component called 'Settings' with that data and getters and setters that is just included/called in each component that needs it (almost every one). I feel like this would be more efficiently utilized as some sort of higher level component.

Is there a way to globally access a data set like this, or a different pattern that would accomplish this?

*(I think my fall back may be to declare it in my top component then pass it individually to each sub component, but that feels like a lot of code that could be simpler.)*

Thank you.

Comment: Just found the global.varname option, not sure if it is a proper solution, but it is working so far.

Comment: Redux is a popular library for handling data flow/global state.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a State Management Container is a good choice, e.g. Redux(https://github.com/reactjs/redux/), Mobx(https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx). You can connect the state and your component by `connect` of `react-redux`, or `inject` of `mobx-react`, they make your component watching the state changes. When some state changed, your component will `receive` new props and will update.

In your scene, you can change state in `Settings` component. With Redux, dispatch an action, and with Mobx, just call an action method.